# How to resolve similar variables in $routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs

For the following case :

```
$routeProvider
.when('/:city/:locality', {
    controller: 'controller1'
})
.when('/:state/:city', {
    controller: 'controller2'
});
```

Is there any way to distinguish between the two URLs on front-end to serve different controllers? For sake of scalability, please assume there can be other cases of similar variable URLs.

Edit: I cannot append constants in route because of SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 routes are exactly the same. They state that there are 2 path params that are dynamic.

You would neednto have something staric in the path for the route to know what your are trying to do.

Such as

`/city/:city/:locality`

And

`/state/:state/:city`

Comment: That's exactly what I can't do because of SEO concerns